Error getting enumeration properties from Win32_OperatingSystem
I faced an issue using WMI with Visual 6.0, C++.
I tried to get the enumeration property from Win32_OperatingSystem
However, when calling the Next function, I get the error code 0x80041018
I am on Windows XP My code
The code provided is missing error handling.
int CSystemInfo::Init()
{
    HRESULT hRes = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    if(FAILED(hRes))
        return 1;

    hRes = CoInitializeSecurity(NULL,
        -1,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_DELEGATE,
        NULL,
        EOAC_NONE,
        NULL
        );
  
    IWbemLocator *locator = NULL;

    hRes = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,
        0,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWbemLocator,
        (LPVOID*)&locator
        ); 

    IWbemServices *services = NULL;
    hRes = locator->ConnectServer(
        BSTR(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL,
        0,
        0,
        &services);
   
    hRes = CoSetProxyBlanket(services,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,
        NULL,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
        0,
        EOAC_NONE
        );

    IEnumWbemClassObject * pEnumerator = NULL;
    hRes = services->ExecQuery(BSTR("WQL"),
        BSTR("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);

    IWbemClassObject *obj=NULL;
    ULONG ret_objs_num;

    hRes = WBEM_S_NO_ERROR;
    while(WBEM_S_NO_ERROR == hRes)
    {
        //ERROR 0x80040018
        hRes = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &obj, &ret_objs_num);

        if(FAILED(hRes) || obj== NULL || ret_objs_num==0)
           break;        
    }

    return 0;
}


If you have any idea, please tell me.

From WMI Error Constants 0x80041018 - WBEM_E_INVALID_QUERY_TYPE - "Requested query language is not supported.".  "I am on Windows XP" - good luck.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem it clearly states : Minimum supported client
Windows Vista. So time to get your OS updated to something newer, or just get rid of that machine completely (security risk)

Hm.. XP has been outdated for some 15 years or so... What are you actually trying to query? Maybe there is another way.

Same result under Win10.
MSDN Oct 2001 says
Windows NT/2000/XP: Requires Windows NT 4.0 SP4 or later
So if it states "Minimum supported client Windows Vista" it means you have to check an old MSDN to get the truth.

You pass BSTR(L"ROOT\\CIMV2") (L prefixed for unicode) and then BSTR("WQL") (not L prefixed). What does BSTR expand to exactly in your code? Try BSTR(L"WQL").
